# How to show a subview when clicking on a button in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I need to show a subview with a button at the bottom of the main view when a button pressed ( this button is in the mainView ) in SwiftUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ZStack to accomplish that.
I put together an example where the buttons trigger the appearance of the subview.

Main View:

```
struct MainView: View {

    @State var isPressed = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom){
            VStack{
                Button {
                    isPressed = true
                } label: {
                    Text("Button MainView")
                }  
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)

            if isPressed == true {
                VStack{
                    SubView(isPressed: $isPressed)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 100)
            }
        
        }
    }
}
```

SubView:

```
struct SubView: View {

    @State var isPressed: Binding<Bool>

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            isPressed.wrappedValue = false
        } label: {
            Text("Button Subview")
        }
    }
}
```

You can replace or extend the button actions and frame sizes as you like.

If you want the button in the MainView to show and hide the SubView, you can use .toggle()

```
Button {
    isPressed.toggle()
} label: {
    Text("Button MainView")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable reply.